# API permisions for LinkedIn

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm struggling with Linked API.

I'm still getting "not enough permissions" when trying to retrive data from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/ads-reporting/ads-reporting?view=li-lms-2022-08&tabs=http
When calling for "leadGenerationMailContactInfoShares" or "oneClickLeads".

I have these permisions on Auth:

"
r_organization_social
r_1st_connections_size
r_organization_admin
r_ads_reporting
r_emailaddress
r_liteprofile
r_basicprofile
r_ads
rw_ads
w_member_social
w_organization_social
"

I tried to go for r_basicprofile and r_liteprofile but neither of that solve it for me.

Anybody knows what and how to request permisons so I can get these data?

Sorry if this is frequent question but I couldn't find anything that would solve it for me.

Thanks